Triangle diagram Hasse diagram in mathematics
I want to draw the following picture where each line - means inclusion as sets (what we call Hasse diagram).
Please ignore the ruled lines.

Please translate the following into English: I'm trying to remove unnecessary parts from the diagram below to obtain the image above, but when I erase certain parts, the entire diagram breaks and it's not working out. I would be grateful for your assistance. Thank you in advance.
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    
    % I only need the arrows for this one.
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    
    % Nice captions.
    \usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
    \setlength{\captionmargin}{25pt}
    
    % New commands to keep things tidy.
    \newcommand{\ket}[1]{$\left|#1\right\rangle$}
    \newcommand{\Om}[1]{\small $\omega_{#1}$}
    \newcommand{\De}[1]{$\Delta_{#1}$}
    \newcommand{\Ga}[1]{$\Gamma_{#1}$}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    % Place the TikZ picture in a figure environment.
    \begin{figure}
    \centerline{
      % Resize it to 5cm wide.
      \resizebox{7cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          scale=0.5,
          level/.style={thick},
          virtual/.style={thick,densely dashed},
          trans/.style={thick,<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth},
          classical/.style={thin,double,<->,shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt,>=stealth}
        ]
        % Draw the energy levels.
        \draw[level] (2cm,-2em) -- (0cm,-2em) node[left] {\ket{a}};
        \draw[level] (2cm,11em) -- (4cm,11em) node[midway,above] {\ket{b}};
        \draw[level] (4cm,-11em) -- (6cm,-11em) node[right] {\ket{c}};
        % Draw the virtual levels.
        \draw[virtual] (2cm,8em) -- (4cm,8em) node[midway,above] {\De{1}};
        \draw[virtual] (4cm,-8em) -- (6cm,-8em) node[midway,below] {\De{2}};
        \draw[virtual] (2cm,-5em) -- (0cm,-5em) node[midway,above] {\De{3}};
        % Draw the transitions.
        \draw[trans] (1cm,-2em) -- (2.5cm,8em) node[midway,left] {\Om{1}};
        \draw[trans] (3.5cm,8em) -- (5cm,-8em) node[midway,right] {\Om{2}};
        \draw[classical] (4.5cm,-8em) -- (1.5cm,-5em) node[midway,below] {\Ga{}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }
    }
    \caption{A level diagram with some transitions drawn in TikZ, resized,
                    and placed in a figure environment.}
    \end{figure}
    
    \end{document}

Result:


Don't use \centerline and don't use \resizebox define the figure at the size you need. What does that code have to do with the image? Where is \De andf \Om defined? As for the image, I'd use tikz-cd instead of doing everything by hand.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I edited so that we can compile it.

Thank you ... However, your problem isn't clear to me: there is no fancy tikz code, no interdependence. Perhaps, if you look up the habdful of relevant tikz-commands, things become more evident. https://tikz.dev/ // Basically replace those \ket macros etc. by your own text. Comment out (and compile) \draw-lines until you have the structure you want. Work from there.

If you don't need the fancy stuff, simple \node and \draw will do the trick.

Put the nodes at the desired spots, then connect them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

% local command to ease input
\newcommand{\edgedesc}[1]{%
  \footnotesize\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % nodes
  \node (D) at (2cm,0) {$D$};
  \node (B) at (0cm,1cm) {$B$};
  \node (C) at (1cm,3cm) {$C$};
  % edges
  \path (B) edge node[above left] {\edgedesc{order more \\ than $E$}} (C);
  \path (C) edge (D);
  \path (D) edge (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{A Hasse diagram}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

Some pieces of advice:

don't use \centerline;
don't use \resizebox unless you precisely know why;
don't scale the TikZ picture unless you precisely know why;
try and read introductory manuals.


If you have to accommodate longer labels, change the placements. Note that you only have to change the node contents, not the names for the coordinates, which are arbitrary strings.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

% local command to ease input
\newcommand{\edgedesc}[1]{%
  \footnotesize\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % nodes
  \node (D) at (3cm,0) {$X(E/L)[2]$};
  \node (B) at (0cm,1.5cm) {$X(E/K)[2]^G$};
  \node (C) at (1.5cm,4cm) {$X(E/K)[2]$};
  % edges
  \path (B) edge node[above left] {\edgedesc{order more \\ than $E$}} (C);
  \path (C) edge (D);
  \path (D) edge (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{A Hasse diagram}

\end{figure}

\end{document}



If I want to replace $B, C, D$ with another formula, for example $C=X(E/K)[2]$, just replacing $C$ with $X(E/K)[2]$ breaks the diagram. How can I replace $B, C, D$ with other expressions like $C=X(E/K)[2], B=X(E/K)[2]^G, D=X(E/L)[2]$?

@BrauerManinobstruction I see no “breaking”. See edit.

I had mistakenly changed the B, C, and D to the right of the node. It's perfect now! Thank you so much.
